# Inverse Laplace: $L^{-1}\left\{ \frac{s}{s^4-s^2+1} \right\}(t)$

Tags: calculus, laplace-transform

Find the following reverse Laplace:
$$L^{-1}\left\{ \dfrac{s}{s^4-s^2+1} \right\}(t)$$
I search in internet and get a result $\dfrac{2\sin\left(\tfrac{t}{2}\right)\sinh \left(\tfrac{\sqrt{3}t}{2} \right)}{\sqrt{3}}$.
I tried some ways, but it's useless. I don't understand why product of **$\sin$** and **$\sinh$** appear here.

I hope to have hints from you. Thank you.

Comment: Complete the square and do some factoring.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. But, I have a different way. I transform the denominator to the form $\left[ \left( s-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \right)^2+\frac{1}{4} \right]\left[ \left( s+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \right)^2+\frac{1}{4} \right]$, then calc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following your transformation, you have
\begin{align*}
L^{-1}\left[\frac{s}{s^4-s^2+1}\right]
&=L^{-1}\left[\frac{s}{((s-\sqrt{3}/2)^2+1/4)((s+\sqrt{3}/2)^2+1/4)}\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}\,L^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{((s-\sqrt{3}/2)^2+1/4)}-\frac{1}{((s+\sqrt{3}/2)^2+1/4)}\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}\left[2e^{\sqrt{3}\,t/2}\sin(t/2)-2e^{-\sqrt{3}\,t/2}\sin(t/2)\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\,\sin(t/2)\,\left[e^{\sqrt{3}\,t/2}-e^{-\sqrt{3}\,t/2}\right]\\
&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\,\sin(t/2)\,\left[\frac{e^{\sqrt{3}\,t/2}-e^{-\sqrt{3}\,t/2}}{2}\right]\\
&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\,\sin(t/2)\,\sinh(\sqrt{3}\,t/2),
\end{align*}
as required.